# If my Mac shut down because of a problem, how do I find the error report?

Tags: error-handling, crash, macos

Sometimes my computer shuts down, and I get the *"Your computer shut down because of a problem"* alert. My question is, where can I find the error message resulting in this? Like if an application quits unexpectedly, there will be a window, and if I click report it will show me detailed descriptions of the error. This allows me to make an estimate why an application crashed. It might say SIGSEGV, meaning the application made a segfault, or a SIGFPE, meaning the application tried to divide by zero or something. But where can I find what causes my *operating system* to crash when it *"Shuts down because of a problem?"* Like did the OS run out of memory? If so, where can I find the error message?

Comment: Welcome to Unix and Linux Stack Exchange. You will probably get better support for this question in the [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Unix (yes I know that MacOS is partly a Unix). It belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/